# Add custom payment info to email order

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, order-email

I've successfully created a magento 2 module with custom payment method using `mage2gen.com`, the problem is i need to show dynamic payment information at order email and pdf. I try check the `app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php` turns out the `$transport['payment_html']` is being rendered by block layout in `app/code/Magento/Payment/Helper/Data.php` but i don't know how to define this payment information block layout for email in my custom module